# Testing students' code in Jupyter with a unittest

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

I'd like my students to be able to check their code as they write it in a Jupyter Notebook by calling a function from an imported module which runs a unittest. This works fine unless the function needs to be checked against objects which are to be picked up in the global scope of the Notebook.

Here's my `check_test` module:

```
import unittest
from IPython.display import Markdown, display

def printmd(string):
    display(Markdown(string))

class Tests(unittest.TestCase):

    def check_add_2(self, add_2):
        val = 5
        self.assertAlmostEqual(add_2(val), 7)

    def check_add_n(self, add_n):
        n = 6
        val = 5
        self.assertAlmostEqual(add_n(val), 11)


check = Tests()
def run_check(check_name, func, hint=False):
    try:
        getattr(check, check_name)(func)
    except check.failureException as e:
        printmd('**<span style="color: red;">FAILED</span>**')
        if hint:
            print('Hint:',  e)
        return
    printmd('**<span style="color: green;">PASSED</span>**')
```

If the Notebook is:

```
In [1]: def add_2(val):
            return val + 2

In [2]: def add_n(val):
            return val + n

In [3]: import test_checks

In [4]: test_checks.run_check('check_add_2', add_2)
        PASSED

In [5]: test_checks.run_check('check_add_n', add_n)
        !!! ERROR !!!
```

The error here is not suprising: `add_n` doesn't know about the `n` I defined in `check_add_n`.

So I got to thinking I could do something like:

```
In [6]: def add_n(val, default_n=None):
            if default_n:
                n = default_n
            return val + n
```

in the Notebook, and then passing `n` in the test:

```
    def check_add_n(self, add_n):
        val = 5
        self.assertAlmostEqual(add_n(val, 6), 11)
```

But this is causing me `UnboundLocalError` headaches down the line because of the assignment of `n`, even within an `if` clause: this is apparently stopping the Notebook from picking up `n` in global scope when it's needed.

For the avoidance of doubt, I don't want insist that `n` is passed as an argument to `add_n`: there could be many such objects used but not changed by the function being tested and I want them resolved in the outer scope.

Any ideas how to go about this?

Comment: While I answered your question I find that `add_n` function to be quite ugly. I'd rather have the students write a function like `def make_adder(n): return lambda val: val +n` and then `add_n = make_adder(n)` and keep that `n` local...

Comment: Thanks for your answer -- this is a big help. I'm not sure the more advanced code you suggest would be easy for them to understand as beginners, however.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can `import __main__` to access the notebook scope:

```
import unittest
from IPython.display import Markdown, display

import __main__


def printmd(string):
    display(Markdown(string))

class Tests(unittest.TestCase):

    def check_add_2(self, add_2):
        val = 5
        self.assertAlmostEqual(add_2(val), 7)

    def check_add_n(self, add_n):
        __main__.n = 6
        val = 5
        self.assertAlmostEqual(add_n(val), 11)


check = Tests()
def run_check(check_name, func, hint=False):
    try:
        getattr(check, check_name)(func)
    except check.failureException as e:
        printmd('**<span style="color: red;">FAILED</span>**')
        if hint:
            print('Hint:',  e)
        return
    printmd('**<span style="color: green;">PASSED</span>**')
```

This gives me a `PASSED` output.

---

This works because when you execute a python file that file is stored in `sys.modules` as the `__main__` module. This is precisely why the `if __name__ == '__main__':` idiom is used. It is possible to import such module and since it is already in the module cache it will not re-execute it or anything.